# Xpath: find div that follows a known div (not nested)

Tags: java, xpath

I need to check that a div that follows some known div does not contains an h3 tag. How do I go about that using only xpath expression?

```
<div>
  <h2></h2>
  ...this is the div I found...
</div>
<div>
  ... need to check for presence of this div ..
  <h3>some text<h3>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the question is not very clear.

If you want to find all `<div>` element following current element that doesn't have child element `<h3>`, you can use XPath expression below :

```
/following-sibling::div[not(h3)]
```

But if you want to find only the first `<div>` element after current element has that criteria, you can try as follow :

```
/following-sibling::div[1][not(h3)]
```

Comment: I am not sure how to describe it better. I am using this with WebDriver. What I want to do is find the first div, then, if it is not followed by a div with h3, I will do some action (like button pressing etc).

Comment: ok, check if any of 2 XPath above works for you. I'm not experienced with WebDriver, so I don't understand the requirement entirely, only understand the XPath part

Comment: yess, after some experimenting I got it working with the second example! Thanks!